# ArcGIS Portal REST API using access token

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-portal

I'm trying to query my Portal's REST API via `my-portal-hostname/webadapter/sharing/rest` in POSTMAN. I am able to generate a token via `/sharing/rest/oauth2/token` however I am not able to then use the token to call other endpoints. After sending a POST request in postman I receive HTML code displaying the portal directory login page. I am trying to call the endpoint to unshare an item from a group.

For the POST request I am sending the token as a key in the form-data body.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably follow a trace of the network requests when it works before trying to go commando.

Comment: I guess you do not provide to much information about what are you sending and what is the real answer. 
Anyway, you can find [in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/esri-es/ArcGIS-REST-API) some Postman collections for the ArcGIS-REST-API. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the replies, the answer was missing a query parameter 'f' to return response as json rather than the default HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was missing a query parameter `f` to return response as json rather than the default HTML.